# Draw a surface from scattered curves

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

I have a few curves determined by some points. I need to plot the surface that they determine. That is, I have this

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]

\begin{axis}[%
width=12cm,height=12cm,
xmin=0,
view={40}{10},
]

\addplot3 [blue]
table[row sep=crcr]{
   1         0   -5.5829\\
   1    5.0000    1.3534\\
   1   10.0000    7.7874\\
   1   15.0000   13.7943\\
   1   20.0000   19.4479\\
   1   25.0000   24.8223\\
   1   30.0000   29.9933\\
   1   35.0000   35.0408\\
   1   40.0000   40.0512\\
   1   45.0000   45.1203\\
   1   50.0000   50.3570\\
   1   55.0000   52.8128\\
   1   60.0000   55.5201\\
   1   65.0000   58.4550\\
   1   70.0000   61.6084\\
   1   75.0000   64.9836\\
   1   80.0000   68.5942\\
   1   85.0000   72.4631\\
   1   90.0000   76.6207\\
   1   95.0000   81.1053\\
   1  100.0000   85.9621\\
   1  105.0000   91.2436\\
   1  110.0000   97.0097\\
   1  115.0000  103.3281\\
   1  120.0000  110.2751\\
   1  125.0000  110.8469\\
   1  130.0000  112.1175\\
   1  135.0000  114.0816\\
   1  140.0000  116.7429\\
   1  145.0000  120.1141\\
   1  150.0000  124.2169\\
   1  155.0000  129.0815\\
   1  160.0000  134.7475\\
};

\addplot3 [blue]
table[row sep=crcr]{
   2         0   -5.3375\\
   2    5.0000    1.5442\\
   2   10.0000    7.9298\\
   2   15.0000   13.8943\\
   2   20.0000   19.5114\\
   2   25.0000   24.8552\\
   2   30.0000   30.0019\\
   2   35.0000   35.0318\\
   2   40.0000   40.0320\\
   2   45.0000   45.0995\\
   2   50.0000   50.3447\\
   2   55.0000   52.7353\\
   2   60.0000   55.3870\\
   2   65.0000   58.2737\\
   2   70.0000   61.3845\\
   2   75.0000   64.7214\\
   2   80.0000   68.2971\\
   2   85.0000   72.1331\\
   2   90.0000   76.2595\\
   2   95.0000   80.7136\\
   2  100.0000   85.5402\\
   2  105.0000   90.7911\\
   2  110.0000   96.5258\\
   2  115.0000  102.8115\\
   2  120.0000  109.7240\\
   2  125.0000  110.2733\\
   2  130.0000  111.5190\\
   2  135.0000  113.4555\\
   2  140.0000  116.0861\\
   2  145.0000  119.4233\\
   2  150.0000  123.4884\\
   2  155.0000  128.3115\\
   2  160.0000  133.9314\\
};

\addplot3 [blue]
table[row sep=crcr]{
   3         0   -6.0748\\
   3    5.0000    0.9575\\
   3   10.0000    7.4763\\
   3   15.0000   13.5574\\
   3   20.0000   19.2753\\
   3   25.0000   24.7045\\
   3   30.0000   29.9213\\
   3   35.0000   35.0058\\
   3   40.0000   40.0445\\
   3   45.0000   45.1332\\
   3   50.0000   50.3808\\
   3   55.0000   52.8484\\
   3   60.0000   55.5586\\
   3   65.0000   58.4873\\
   3   70.0000   61.6252\\
   3   75.0000   64.9753\\
   3   80.0000   68.5508\\
   3   85.0000   72.3737\\
   3   90.0000   76.4738\\
   3   95.0000   80.8881\\
   3  100.0000   85.6606\\
   3  105.0000   90.8424\\
   3  110.0000   96.4915\\
   3  115.0000  102.6739\\
   3  120.0000  109.4633\\
   3  125.0000  110.2664\\
   3  130.0000  111.7478\\
   3  135.0000  113.9048\\
   3  140.0000  116.7442\\
   3  145.0000  120.2812\\
   3  150.0000  124.5397\\
   3  155.0000  129.5523\\
   3  160.0000  135.3603\\
};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But I need this

[image]

How can I do? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first example I cut down your code a lot to only first five rows of data, on contrary, in the second example I doubled your data.

I switched to a 3D graph type (`surf`) and started digging in the pgfplots manual http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf. The key switch was `mesh/rows=3`. You can see an improvement in the figures below (from the left figure to the middle one). Then I figured out an interesting option `faceted color=green`, but it is not helping us as we need lines drawn only in one direction, see the figure below on the right side. Maybe that's a potential feature for dr. Feuersänger and his colleagues. Because in this particular case we would need `x faceted color` and `y faceted color`.

I enclose an example, the key line is line number 9 which I was changing. I put a percent sign at the beginning of the line, before `faceted`, and not at all.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=12cm, height=12cm,
xmin=0,view={40}{10},]
\addplot3 [surf, 
  mesh/rows=3, faceted color=green, line width=2pt,
  ]
table {
   1         0   -5.5829
   1    5.0000    1.3534
   1   10.0000    7.7874
   1   15.0000   13.7943
   1   20.0000   19.4479
   2         0   -5.3375
   2    5.0000    1.5442
   2   10.0000    7.9298
   2   15.0000   13.8943
   2   20.0000   19.5114
   3         0   -6.0748
   3    5.0000    0.9575
   3   10.0000    7.4763
   3   15.0000   13.5574
   3   20.0000   19.2753
   };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: example 1]

Then it was the right time to use layering of graphs. After drawing the `surf` graph we just needed to put (poly)lines on it. As a drawing bonus I activated the `shader` option. This drawing strategy illustrates next source code and a preview of the figure. The only disadvantage is that I needed to rearrange your data and double them. I am sure we can optimize it somehow, but I am leaving the graph as it is for further improvements.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{mystyle/.style={green, line width=3pt}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
\begin{axis}[width=12cm, height=12cm, 
xmin=0,view={100}{55}, colorbar,
]

% The shaded area below green lines...
% Draw me first!
\addplot3 [surf, mesh/rows=3, 
faceted color=none,  % try % faceted color=green
shader=interp, 
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
   1         0   -5.5829\\
   1    5.0000    1.3534\\
   1   10.0000    7.7874\\
   1   15.0000   13.7943\\
   1   20.0000   19.4479\\
   1   25.0000   24.8223\\
   1   30.0000   29.9933\\
   1   35.0000   35.0408\\
   1   40.0000   40.0512\\
   1   45.0000   45.1203\\
   1   50.0000   50.3570\\
   1   55.0000   52.8128\\
   1   60.0000   55.5201\\
   1   65.0000   58.4550\\
   1   70.0000   61.6084\\
   1   75.0000   64.9836\\
   1   80.0000   68.5942\\
   1   85.0000   72.4631\\
   1   90.0000   76.6207\\
   1   95.0000   81.1053\\
   1  100.0000   85.9621\\
   1  105.0000   91.2436\\
   1  110.0000   97.0097\\
   1  115.0000  103.3281\\
   1  120.0000  110.2751\\
   1  125.0000  110.8469\\
   1  130.0000  112.1175\\
   1  135.0000  114.0816\\
   1  140.0000  116.7429\\
   1  145.0000  120.1141\\
   1  150.0000  124.2169\\
   1  155.0000  129.0815\\
   1  160.0000  134.7475\\
   2         0   -5.3375\\
   2    5.0000    1.5442\\
   2   10.0000    7.9298\\
   2   15.0000   13.8943\\
   2   20.0000   19.5114\\
   2   25.0000   24.8552\\
   2   30.0000   30.0019\\
   2   35.0000   35.0318\\
   2   40.0000   40.0320\\
   2   45.0000   45.0995\\
   2   50.0000   50.3447\\
   2   55.0000   52.7353\\
   2   60.0000   55.3870\\
   2   65.0000   58.2737\\
   2   70.0000   61.3845\\
   2   75.0000   64.7214\\
   2   80.0000   68.2971\\
   2   85.0000   72.1331\\
   2   90.0000   76.2595\\
   2   95.0000   80.7136\\
   2  100.0000   85.5402\\
   2  105.0000   90.7911\\
   2  110.0000   96.5258\\
   2  115.0000  102.8115\\
   2  120.0000  109.7240\\
   2  125.0000  110.2733\\
   2  130.0000  111.5190\\
   2  135.0000  113.4555\\
   2  140.0000  116.0861\\
   2  145.0000  119.4233\\
   2  150.0000  123.4884\\
   2  155.0000  128.3115\\
   2  160.0000  133.9314\\
   3         0   -6.0748\\
   3    5.0000    0.9575\\
   3   10.0000    7.4763\\
   3   15.0000   13.5574\\
   3   20.0000   19.2753\\
   3   25.0000   24.7045\\
   3   30.0000   29.9213\\
   3   35.0000   35.0058\\
   3   40.0000   40.0445\\
   3   45.0000   45.1332\\
   3   50.0000   50.3808\\
   3   55.0000   52.8484\\
   3   60.0000   55.5586\\
   3   65.0000   58.4873\\
   3   70.0000   61.6252\\
   3   75.0000   64.9753\\
   3   80.0000   68.5508\\
   3   85.0000   72.3737\\
   3   90.0000   76.4738\\
   3   95.0000   80.8881\\
   3  100.0000   85.6606\\
   3  105.0000   90.8424\\
   3  110.0000   96.4915\\
   3  115.0000  102.6739\\
   3  120.0000  109.4633\\
   3  125.0000  110.2664\\
   3  130.0000  111.7478\\
   3  135.0000  113.9048\\
   3  140.0000  116.7442\\
   3  145.0000  120.2812\\
   3  150.0000  124.5397\\
   3  155.0000  129.5523\\
   3  160.0000  135.3603\\
};

% Replacement for x faceted color and y faceted color. :-)
% Perhaps this is a feature for the developers?
\addplot3 [mystyle]
table[row sep=crcr]{
   1         0   -5.5829\\
   1    5.0000    1.3534\\
   1   10.0000    7.7874\\
   1   15.0000   13.7943\\
   1   20.0000   19.4479\\
   1   25.0000   24.8223\\
   1   30.0000   29.9933\\
   1   35.0000   35.0408\\
   1   40.0000   40.0512\\
   1   45.0000   45.1203\\
   1   50.0000   50.3570\\
   1   55.0000   52.8128\\
   1   60.0000   55.5201\\
   1   65.0000   58.4550\\
   1   70.0000   61.6084\\
   1   75.0000   64.9836\\
   1   80.0000   68.5942\\
   1   85.0000   72.4631\\
   1   90.0000   76.6207\\
   1   95.0000   81.1053\\
   1  100.0000   85.9621\\
   1  105.0000   91.2436\\
   1  110.0000   97.0097\\
   1  115.0000  103.3281\\
   1  120.0000  110.2751\\
   1  125.0000  110.8469\\
   1  130.0000  112.1175\\
   1  135.0000  114.0816\\
   1  140.0000  116.7429\\
   1  145.0000  120.1141\\
   1  150.0000  124.2169\\
   1  155.0000  129.0815\\
   1  160.0000  134.7475\\
   };
\addplot3 [mystyle]
table[row sep=crcr]{
   2         0   -5.3375\\
   2    5.0000    1.5442\\
   2   10.0000    7.9298\\
   2   15.0000   13.8943\\
   2   20.0000   19.5114\\
   2   25.0000   24.8552\\
   2   30.0000   30.0019\\
   2   35.0000   35.0318\\
   2   40.0000   40.0320\\
   2   45.0000   45.0995\\
   2   50.0000   50.3447\\
   2   55.0000   52.7353\\
   2   60.0000   55.3870\\
   2   65.0000   58.2737\\
   2   70.0000   61.3845\\
   2   75.0000   64.7214\\
   2   80.0000   68.2971\\
   2   85.0000   72.1331\\
   2   90.0000   76.2595\\
   2   95.0000   80.7136\\
   2  100.0000   85.5402\\
   2  105.0000   90.7911\\
   2  110.0000   96.5258\\
   2  115.0000  102.8115\\
   2  120.0000  109.7240\\
   2  125.0000  110.2733\\
   2  130.0000  111.5190\\
   2  135.0000  113.4555\\
   2  140.0000  116.0861\\
   2  145.0000  119.4233\\
   2  150.0000  123.4884\\
   2  155.0000  128.3115\\
   2  160.0000  133.9314\\
   };
\addplot3 [mystyle]
table[row sep=crcr]{
   3         0   -6.0748\\
   3    5.0000    0.9575\\
   3   10.0000    7.4763\\
   3   15.0000   13.5574\\
   3   20.0000   19.2753\\
   3   25.0000   24.7045\\
   3   30.0000   29.9213\\
   3   35.0000   35.0058\\
   3   40.0000   40.0445\\
   3   45.0000   45.1332\\
   3   50.0000   50.3808\\
   3   55.0000   52.8484\\
   3   60.0000   55.5586\\
   3   65.0000   58.4873\\
   3   70.0000   61.6252\\
   3   75.0000   64.9753\\
   3   80.0000   68.5508\\
   3   85.0000   72.3737\\
   3   90.0000   76.4738\\
   3   95.0000   80.8881\\
   3  100.0000   85.6606\\
   3  105.0000   90.8424\\
   3  110.0000   96.4915\\
   3  115.0000  102.6739\\
   3  120.0000  109.4633\\
   3  125.0000  110.2664\\
   3  130.0000  111.7478\\
   3  135.0000  113.9048\\
   3  140.0000  116.7442\\
   3  145.0000  120.2812\\
   3  150.0000  124.5397\\
   3  155.0000  129.5523\\
   3  160.0000  135.3603\\
   };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: example 2]

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exactly what I need! You really helped me!

Comment: Anytime! I am glad I could be of assistance.

Comment: @Malipivo I received your suggestion and I will think about such a feature.

Comment: @Malipivo you could archieve the green line overlay by means of and `\addplot3` based on the *same* data - with just one change to the data file: you would need to introduce empty lines after each scanline (in your context, an "empty line" would just contain the line separator `\\`). This would instruct the line plot handler to add an interruption.

Comment: @Christian Feuersänger Thank you and thank you, that's good to know!